# Regex - Return 1 character prior to match

Tags: regex

Im trying to write some regex that will return 1 character prior to a match.  For example

```
:record1: Has text here with "\n" as the end of line \n
however, there can be multiple line \n
and I dont know how many before I get to the next record \n
:record2: has some other date in it \n
```

My current regex to try and find the end of record1 looks like this

```
(\n)(?=:record2:)
```

Id like to capture the last \n, but so I can get its position.  Any thoughts on how to capture the character immediately prior to the a string match?

Comment: `.*?(\n):record2:` would capture the last `\n` before the string.  But what do you mean by "position," and what tool/language are you using?

Comment: why don't you just split your string by `\n:record:` (and remove the digit)?

Comment: Im using a proprietary tool for converting text files to xml.  the tool allows you to define start and end tags using regex expressions.  I want to define an end tag that identifies the \n prior to :record2:

Comment: have u tried my answer?

Comment: @antoni sorry, I dont have the much control.  its like a linear parse.  you start and have to account for every char to be able to generate the xml

Comment: @TheUltimateHack, please consider marking as resolved or give your own answer for next readers with same questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you don't want to just split your string by `\n:record:` (and remove the digit)which would be simpler and faster, then what you are looking for is a called a [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html): `\\n\n(?=:record\d+:)`.

You can view the demo here: https://regex101.com/r/im02XA/1